# Documents(file) name from Shared Documents in SP 2013 using powershell script

Tags: powershell

How do i get each document or file name from Shared Documents using PowerShell script.

Thanks

Comment: You want to download all the documents?

Comment: No i dont want to download. But just need the names of it using loop in powershell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use below Powershell.

```
$spweb = get-spweb -identity "http://yourdomain/yourweb"
# Use the "pretty name" of your library below
$list = $spweb.lists["Your Library"]
$listItems = $list.Items
# For each item
foreach ($listItem in $listItems)
{ 
   $DocumentTitle = $listItem.Name
   write-host "FileTitle -> $DocumentTitle"   
}

#Clean up
$spWeb.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Get-SPWeb http://sharepoint/sites/xyz|
   Select -ExpandProperty Lists |
   Where { $_.Title -eq "Shared Documents" } |
   Select -ExpandProperty Fields | Select Title, InternalName
```

For more informaiton:

http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint/windows-powershell-scripts-sharepoint-info-files-pagesweb-parts

Following code will also help you

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Function GetFiles($Folder)
{ 
   Write-Host "+"$Folder.Name

    foreach($file in $Folder.Files)
    {   
        Write-Host "`t" $file.Name
    }
     #Loop through all subfolders and call the function recursively
     foreach ($SubFolder in $Folder.SubFolders)
        {
            if($SubFolder.Name -ne "Forms")
            {  
                Write-Host "`t" -NoNewline
                GetFiles($Subfolder)

            }
        }
 }

#Get the Site collection 
$Site= Get-SPSite "http://sharepoint.com" 
       #Loop throuh all Sub Sites
       foreach($Web in $Site.AllWebs)
       {
        Write-Host "-----------------------------------------------------"
        Write-Host "Site Name: '$($web.Title)' at $($web.URL)"
        Write-Host "-----------------------------------------------------"
        foreach($list in $Web.Lists)
        {
           #Filter Doc Libs, Eliminate Hidden ones
            if(($List.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary") -and ($List.Hidden -eq $false) )
               { 
                GetFiles($List.RootFolder)
               }
        }
       }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the script that will print the names of all items in a library.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb <web address>
$list = $web.Lists["<document library/list name>"]
$items = $list.Items
foreach($i in $items){
   Write-Host $i.Name
}
```